# Difference between curl and libcurl in Ubuntu

Tags: curl

What is the difference between installing curl (`sudo apt install curl`)  and installing libcurl  (`sudo apt install libcurl-dev`)

Comment: `curl` is the cli and `libcurl` is the library. The cli is just the frontend which uses the library. That is a quite common concept in linux and programming generally.

Answer (score 3):

You're asking about `curl` and `libcurl-dev`.

`curl` is an application, which depends on `libcurl4` to run. You can write other apps than curl to use `libcurl4`.

`libcurl-dev` is a [virtual package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/libcurl-dev), provided by the following packages:

> ##### Packages providing libcurl-dev
>
> ###### libcurl4-gnutls-dev
>
> development files and documentation for libcurl (GnuTLS flavour)
>
> ###### libcurl4-nss-dev
>
> development files and documentation for libcurl (NSS flavour)
>
> ###### libcurl4-openssl-dev
>
> development files and documentation for libcurl (OpenSSL flavour)

So this provides tools and documentation if you want to develop an application that uses `libcurl4`, `libcurl3-gnutls` or `libcurl3-nss`. Further information can be found under each package under `libcurl-dev`.

Comment: by default which  libcurl library  `curl` command uses in ubuntu?

Comment: It's stated in my answer - `libcurl4`.

Comment: I see. then curl uses `libcurl-dev`  and which intern has all of these 3 libraries in it ?

Comment: Sorry, you have to research additional details if you need them.